# In what time period the series Arang and the Magistrate set?

Tags: historical-accuracy, arang-and-the-magistrate

Based on the costumes and the setting,  which dynasty or time period served as an inspiration for the historical drama series *Arang*?

[image: Poster of male and female protagonists from Arang]

Answer (score 1):

The [Joseon Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseon) founded by Yi Seong-gye in July 1392 and was replaced by the Korean Empire in October 1897.

Confirmed by the [show's wiki entry.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arang_and_the_Magistrate)

> The drama is based on famous folklore, as most ghost stories are: During the Joseon era in the city of Miryang,